# WebSelfStorage API Reservation Date issue

Tags: php, rest, api

I am working on a friend's self storage website.  They use WebSelfStorage for the Tenant Management Software.  The api documentation can be found at https://api.webselfstorage.com/

I have successfully been able to retrieve the information required.  You can test the code here: http://broken.press/testing/hydry/ . I have been able to send selected information to a reservation page, but when you go to set the reservation you get this error:

> array(4) { ["Parameter"]=> string(14) "ReservationDay" ["Reason"]=> string(97) "Unrecognized date format. Please use one of the datetime strings provided in the location request" ["Success"]=> bool(false) ["ErrorMessage"]=> string(34) "An invalid parameter was specified" }

According to the documentation, it appears that it requires ISO8601 DateTime format, so I formatted it that way (current code).  I have also set the format to match rather than convert it to ISO8601 (didn't work either).  Below is the code (username, password, and Authorization removed for privacy).

**SubmitReservation.php**

```
    <body>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<?php //Submit Reservation
$username = XXXXXX;
$password = XXXXXX;
$url = "https://api.webselfstorage.com/wssapi/v2/reservation/1025140";
$header = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX',
);
$dateFormat = 'n/j/Y';
$dateString = $_POST['moveIn'];

$date = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($dateString));

if ($_POST['mobile'] = ""){
    $phone = $_POST['home'];
} else {
    $phone = $_POST['mobile'];
    }
$data_array =  array(
   "FirstName"        => $_POST['fname'],
   "LastName"            => $_POST['lname'],
   "Phone"              => $phone,
   "Address1"            => $_POST['street'],
   "City"               => $_POST['city'],
   "State"               => $_POST['state'],
   "Zip"                     => $_POST['zip'],
   "Email"               => $_POST['email'],
   "UnitID"              => $_POST['unitID'],
   "MoveInDate"          => $date,
   "ReservationDay"  => $date //<< Edited
);

/*$reservationOptions = new stdClass();
    $reservationOptions->firstName = $_POST['fname'];
    $reservationOptions->lastName = $_POST['lname'];
    $reservationOptions->email = $_POST['email'];
    $reservationOptions->mobilePhone = $_POST['mobile'];
    $reservationOptions->homePhone = $_POST['home'];
    $reservationOptions->street1 = $_POST['street'];
    $reservationOptions->city = $_POST['city'];
    $reservationOptions->state = $_POST['state'];
    $reservationOptions->zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $reservationOptions->moveinDate = $_POST['moveIn'];
    $reservationOptions->unitTypeId = $_POST['unit-name'];*/

// Make API Call
function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
   $curl = curl_init();

   switch ($method){
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
      case "PUT":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
         break;
      default:
         if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
   }

   // OPTIONS:
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization: Basic 2f5a1329-43f9-40d6-93c5-8e36a00ef725',
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

   // EXECUTE:
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
}


$make_call = callAPI('POST', 'https://api.webselfstorage.com/wssapi/v2/reservation/1025140', json_encode($data_array));
$response = json_decode($make_call, true);
$errors   = $response['response']['errors'];

var_dump($response);?><br/>
<?php
print_r($response);
echo $date;
?><br/>
        Thank you for your request.  You will be redirected in just a second.
<script>
    //setTimeout(function () {
     //  window.top.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
    //}, 2000);
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Reservation.php (Form)**

```
<title>Reservation Form</title>
    <?php 
    $unitName = $_POST['unitname'];
    $sessionId = $_SESSION['sessionId'];
    $facility = "1025140";
    $unitID = $_POST['unitID'];
    ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: '+2M',
        firstDay: 0
    });

    function nonWorkingDates(date){
        var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
        var closedDates = [[7, 4, 2019]];
        var closedDays = [[Sunday]];
        for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
            if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
                return [false];
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
            date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
            date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
                return [false];
            }
        }

        return [true];
    }




}); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form_container">
<form id="reservation" name="submitReservation.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-title"><p>Apply For This Unit</p></div>
  <div class="form-description"><p>Fill out this form, and a manager will be in touch shortly to confirm your move-in date.
  Applying for:<div class="unit_type"><?php echo $unitName;?></p><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $unitID;?>" name="unit-name" id="unit-name"></div></p></div>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name"><br/>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br/>
    <div class="form-sub">Phone Numbers:</div><br/>
    <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Cell Phone"><br/>
    <input type="tel" name="home" id="home" placeholder="Home Phone"><br/>
    <div class="form-sub">Address:</div><br/>
      <input type="text" name="street" id="street" placeholder="Street Address"><br/>
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City"><br/>
        <select name="state" id="state" >
    //Redacted all 50 state options for space
        </select>
      <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip">
    <br/>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="moveIn" id="datepicker" placeholder="Move-In Date"> <br/>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="submitReservation.php">Set Reservation</button>
  </p>

    </div>
</form>
```

I simply need the information from the Reservation Form to be added via API into the Reservation System of WebSelfStorage.

Answer (score 0):

you should change 
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
to 
Content-Type:application/json

Comment: I will try that